# JRadiobuttons getting automatically selected

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I have 5 identical panels in my tabbed pane and they have a button group of 4 radio buttons.. If I select any of d buttons on a panel and move to the next panel, the one that was selected on d previous pane becomes automatically selected. So if I select option B on a question, when I navigate to all other questions, that option is selected.
 I only have one panel built using GUI builder, the other ones are created programmatically to be identical to the first one.
The slightest help would be appreciated

Comment: Show some code. Sounds like you're using the same `ButtonGroup` reference for each panel, but that's just a guess. If that's the case, either clear the selection via [`ButtonGroup#clearSelection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection()) or use a different `ButtonGroup` for each panel.

Comment: How can I use different button group?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I have made a frame with 2 tabbed panes and 2 radio buttons. you can add more panels and buttons to it.
Select one button from tab1 and it won't be selected automatically on tab 2. On tab 2 you can get a new selection.

```
public class test {

JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("radio1");;
JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("radio2");
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

public test() {

bg.add(r1);
bg.add(r2);
panel1.add(r1);
panel1.add(r2);
r1 = new JRadioButton("radio1");
r2 = new JRadioButton("radio2");
panel2.add(r1);
panel2.add(r2);
tab.addTab("tab1", panel1);
tab.addTab("tab2", panel2);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setContentPane(tab);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new test();
}
}
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks Bhavna, I got to fix it using some reusability principles, we actually don't need to create a tab for each radiobutton. A single pane and a single radiobutton with do if we use data structures adequately.. I was able to implement it in Swing and now that I'm doing JavaFX, I implemented it too. Sorry this us coming late, thanks